# How to apply Laravel + inertia + vue3 app changes to live server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am working on a client's project, I have done changes in Vue and scss files, I want to know to can I deploy these changes to the live server.
The live website is on the digital ocean server. and its SSR(server-side rendering is on)

```
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix && mix --mix-config=webpack.ssr.mix.js",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-server": "mix watch --mix-config=webpack.ssr.mix.js",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "mix --production && mix --production --mix-config=webpack.ssr.mix.js",
        "production": "mix --production",
        "server": "nodemon public/js/ssr.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "@vue/babel-plugin-jsx": "^1.1.1",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
        "vue-loader": "^17.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
        "@duannx/vue-client-only": "^1.0.3",
        "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",
        "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.6.0",
        "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.7",
        "@inertiajs/server": "^0.1.0",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.23.0",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.31",
        "@vue/server-renderer": "^3.2.31",
        "@vuepic/vue-datepicker": "^3.1.0",
        "algoliasearch": "^4.13.1",
        "inertia-title": "^1.0.2",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "sprintf-js": "^1.1.2",
        "vue": "^3.2.31",
        "vue-instantsearch": "^4.3.3",
        "vue-slick-carousel": "^1.0.6",
        "vue-stripe-js": "^1.0.0",
        "vue-timer-hook": "^1.0.0",
        "vue-toastification": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
        "vue3-autocounter": "^1.0.6",
        "vue3-datepicker": "^0.3.2",
        "vue3-lazyload": "^0.2.5-beta",
        "vue3-select2-component": "^0.1.7",
        "vuedraggable": "^4.1.0",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're happy with your local changes, you can probably just push them on some CSM (like Git) to let the CI pipelines build the whole thing for production.

Comment: CI pipeline means?

Comment: This was an example. But basically any kind of code that will bundle your app before a production release.

Comment: the site is already deployed on server. ijust have to push my changes in css files

Comment: Doesn't really changes the process if it's JS, CSS or text only.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation.
Replace the old files with the new files on the live server.
Then install node.js and npm on the live server, if it isn't already.
Then run 'npm run dev'. Anytime you change a javascript file, like vue, you need to use npm run dev to register the changes.
Hope this is helpful. It seems to work for me.

Comment: We have HMR nowadays, this approach seems quite cumbersome and annoying to use on a daily basis.